# WRT54GL Tomato Router in Client wireless mode to an iPhone Personal Hotspot

Tags: iphone, hotspot, tomato, wrt54gl

I am trying to connect a router with Tomato firmware to an iPhone 4.  The goal is to connect to the Personal Hotspot in Client Wireless mode.

This should allow wired and wireless users to connect to the router rather then the iPhone.  In theory this should be possible but I am having difficulty.

**Router**

- Linksys WRT54GL
- Tomato 1.28.1816 firmware

**iPhone**

- iPhone 4
- iOS 5.1 (9B176)
- Carrier Rogers Wireless
- Personal Hotspot works with other devices, wifi/bluetooth/usb

**iPhone Personal Hotspot settings**

- Mode:    B/G
- Security:   WPA or WPA2 Personal
- Encryption: AES
- Router IP:  172.20.10.1
- Subnet:     172.20.10.0
- Min IP:     172.20.10.2
- Max IP:     172.20.10.14
- maximum number of wireless tethered hosts is 5

I have followed the directions here:
http://www.wi-fiplanet.com/tutorials/article.php/3810281

Ensured that the router subnet does not 'collide' with the iPhone subnet.

Here is the configuration of the Tomato 'Basic - Network - Wireless' section:

[image]

I have tried several variations of this configuration, but nothing seems to work.

**NOTE: I have successfully connected to my own wifi network in Wireless Client mode, so I am confident that there are no bad cables or other hardware issues.**

I would prefer to use Tomato, but DD-WRT maybe my only other option.

Comment: Might help to temporarily disable the security, just to ease the troubleshooting...